# Write Output CSV has wrong/weird format

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm doing Web Scraping - I have a list that contains around 140 page titles but after writing it to CSV, the format of titles become very weird. In Python using Spyder, I can see proper results but only after writing it, in CSV it becomes weird.

This is my write code. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
o_file = open('headlines.csv','w')
with o_file:
    writer = csv.writer(o_file, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerows(h_list)
```

Output is coming like this in CSV (space after every alphabet and quotes after every word):

```
H e r e ' s " " W h y " " T h e r e " " W a s " " a n " " E m p t y " " S e a t " " N e x t " " t o " " P r i n c e " " W i l l i a m " " a t " " t h e " " R o y a l " " W e d d i n g
```

Also, in CSV at some rows there is data in Second column as well. While the work I'm doing has a list with 140 page titles which I can see in Spyder then how and why it is giving some page titles in second column as well? Any thoughts?

Comment: what does `h_list` contains?

Comment: I believe it's because your delimiter is a space. Try excluding the delimiter completely. Otherwise more info is needed.

Comment: remove "delimiter= ' '"

Comment: It appears that each element of `h_list` must be a string, each of which is being interpreted by `csv.writer.writerows()` as the data comprising a row—so it inserts the delimiter between each element in the row when formatting the output. Each element in this case is a single character of the string. You need to put each string in `h_list` into separate sublists something like this: `[["first"], ["second"], ["third"], etc...]`.

Comment: @SagunShrestha h_list is a list that contains 140 sentences

Comment: @AaronBrandhagen if I remove delimiter, the whole sentence is split into alphabets and each column holds only one alphabet

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the idea. But few questions: In Spyder, h_list  variable shows the exact proper result but while only writing the output in CSV the output is weird. Is there something to do with write script that I had shared? Do I need to change something there? I'm sorry if my questions are silly as I am a beginner in this field. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Pragyanshu: Yes, it's because the code that writes out the csv file isn't doing it correctly. If you [edit] your question and add a (short) sample of the contents of `h_list`, I, or someone else, will probably be able show you how to do it properly. It would also useful for you to show what the desired output put into the csv file would be for this added data.

Comment: Add the parameter 'end= "" ' after the delimiter. If that doesn't work, use the end and delimiter params and remove the quoting param. I would think one of those options would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can avoid loops and instead implement a single line solution for this:

Convert your **h_list** to a dataframe **df** and then use **df.to_csv** to save as csv format

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Headline':h_list})
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

The output **file.csv** will have list elements in different rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you *still* haven't provided the requested additional information I (and others) have requested, so at best the following is just an educated guess—that implements what I suggested to you in one of my comments (i.e. to convert `h_list` into a list-of-lists containing a single string):

```
import csv

h_list = [
    "Here's Why There Was an Empty Seat Next to Prince William at the Royal Wedding",
    "NASA wrestles with what to do with International Space Station after 2024",
    "Father-son team pilot plane from Seattle to Amsterdam",
    # etc...
]

with open('headlines.csv', 'w', newline='') as o_file:
    writer = csv.writer(o_file)
    # Make each line in h_list a row with a single headline string in it.
    writer.writerows([headline] for headline in h_list)

print('done')
```

Contents of `headlines.csv` after execution:

```
Here's Why There Was an Empty Seat Next to Prince William at the Royal Wedding
NASA wrestles with what to do with International Space Station after 2024
Father-son team pilot plane from Seattle to Amsterdam
```

I not sure if that's what you want in the `csv` file or not—since it doesn't really make much sense to use that format when there's only a single value (field) in each row (so no delimiters are needed)—but, if nothing else, perhaps it will help you figure-out the right thing to do.

Comment: THANKS A TON! Your code works perfectly fine. I'm sorry if I was short of giving inputs from my side. But you had understood and illustrated is exactly what I was looking. Thanks Master! _/\_ :)